# Mapping promises as part of a .then() chain

Tags: javascript, promise

#### What I'm trying to do:

I'm trying to create a function to allow me to abstract this:

```
somePromise(options)
  .then(anotherPromise)
  .then(results =>
    Promise.all(results.map(result =>
      someOtherPromise(result.url)
        .then(anotherPromise)
        .then(val => Object.assign(val, { hello: "world" }))
      )));
```

into:

```
somePromise(options)
  .then(anotherPromise)
  .thenMapAll(results, result =>
    someOtherPromise(result.url)
      .then(anotherPromise)
      .then(val => Object.assign(val, { hello: "world" }))
  );
```

i.e., abstract a `.thenMapAll` function, that acts in place of `.then` to map an array of results to an array of promises which are all awaited by `Promise.all`.

#### What I've achieved so far:

This:

```
Promise.mapAll = (array, fn) => 
  Promise.all(array.map(val => fn(val)));

Promise.prototype.thenMapAll = (array, fn) => 
  Promise.mapAll(array, val => fn(val));
```

which basically works! However, the order in which the Promises resolve is not correct. It seems that the Promises created by `.thenMap` always run befoe those of any preceding `.then`:

```
new Promise((res, rej) => res("a"))
  .then(console.log) // Neither syntax makes a difference.
  .then(() => new Promise((res,rej) => res(console.log("b"))))
  .thenMapAll([ "c", "d", "e" ], console.log);

/* Outputs: 
**   c
**   d
**   e
**   a
**   b
*/
```

#### Question!

Why is the order of the Promises incorrect? How can I get the Promises to run in the correct order?

Comment: cool question! could it be that your `.thenMapAll` isn't waiting for a `resolve()` call? Like I can't see anything in your code that waits for promise to resolve, it just seems to be running. The 'event loop' is the reason that they are coming early in your example, even though your example resolves essentially immediately.

Comment: `.then` adds a callback to the chain which gets called internally at the appropriate time… `.thenMapAll` does not add the callback for later use but just runs it immediately.

Comment: using arrow function in a prototype function declaration seems an odd choice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`thenMapAll` is being invoked immediately as opposed to adding its promises to the current promise chain, what you want is:

```
Promise.mapAll = (array, fn) => 
  Promise.all(array.map(val => fn(val)));

Promise.prototype.thenMapAll = function(array, fn) {
  return this.then(() => {
    return Promise.mapAll(array, val => fn(val));
  });
};
```

which outputs:

```
a
b
c
d
e
```

because now `thenMapAll` is invoking `Promise.mapAll` inside of a call to `this.then(() => {})` which is adding it to the existing promise chain as opposed to creating a brand new one which runs right away. Since we're adding a function to `Promise.prototype` the `this` keyword refers to the current Promise instance, so this is why we're allowed to add on to the promise chain in this way.

Comment: Amazing, didn't even think about `this.then`. Thank you!

Comment: `this.then` would not work if you used arrow function for `Promise.prototype.thenMapAll = (array, fn) => ...` by the way

Answer (score 0):

There's a mistake in your desired syntax: `results` is undefined. It should come from the promise that the method is called upon - it's the result value - so you should omit the argument:

```
somePromise(options)
  .then(anotherPromise)
  .thenMapAll(  result =>
//            ^
    someOtherPromise(result.url)
      .then(anotherPromise)
      .then(val => Object.assign(val, { hello: "world" }))
  );
```

And in your `thenMapAll` method you will need to wait for the receiver promise (`this`) to get this result, by installing a `then` handler:

```
Promise.mapAll = (array, fn) => Promise.all(array.map(fn));
Promise.prototype.thenMapAll = function(fn) {
  return this.then(array => Promise.mapAll(array, fn));
};
```